# Check if files in a list exists

Tags: c#, list, file

I have a file named list.txt, in this file I have a list of filepaths like this:

```
Directory1/DirectoryZ/file.txt
Directory2/DirectoryX/file1.txt
Directory3/DirectoryY/file2.txt
etc...
```

I've tried something like this:

```
if (File.Exists("list.txt"))
{
    string[] files = File.ReadAllLines("list.txt");
    if (File.Exists(files.ToString()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(files[1]);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot find som' files");
}

Console.ReadKey(true);
```

My Question:

How can I check if those files exists in that specific path by reading the file, and then, after checking, if a file is missing to raise a error?

P.S:
Sorry if my question is duplicated, I haven't found a topic with a question like mine.

Comment: No need to check if list.txt exists or not. Handle FileNotFoundException instead. You can make use of parallel programming if you are using .Net 4 or above to simultaneously check if data in file points to a file or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (File.Exists("list.txt"))
{
    string[] files = File.ReadAllLines("list.txt");
    foreach(string fileName in files)
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(fileName);
        }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot find som' files");
}

Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: Throwing exceptions explicitly? May be it is my pet peeve, as I do not like this. You should store missing file paths and inform user later about it.

Comment: Worked! Thank you @David Pilkington !

Comment: Used Console.WriteLine("Missing file: {0}", filename) instead of throw new FileNotFoundException(fileName);

Comment: @danish it was added because of this line " and then, after checking, if a file is missing to raise a error?" from the OP

Comment: Yeah, it was probably language thing. OP may not be native English speaker. I may be wrong, I am no native English speaker either.

Answer (score 3):

A different approach. Getting all the files names that don't exist

```
    string fileList = @"d:\temp\list.txt";
    if (File.Exists(fileList))
    {
        var files = File.ReadAllLines(fileList).Where(x => !File.Exists(x));
        if(files.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach(string missing in files)
               Console.WriteLine("File missing: " + missing);
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Some files are missing");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot find list file");
    }
```

If you are not interested to get the list of missing files your could change to

```
    var file = File.ReadAllLines(fileList).FirstOrDefault(x => !File.Exists(x));
    if(file != null)
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File missing " + file.ToString());
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) G:\WOK\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 16 27 ConsoleApplication1

Comment: It's working now, thank you. @David Pilkington gave me exactly what i asked for :)

Comment: No problem, my answer is just to show how you could avoid an explicit foreach. If you are not interested in the list of missing files you could also change the Where with a FirstOrDefault to stop the enumeration at the first missing file and throw the exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over your string array:

```
string[] files = File.ReadAllLines("list.txt");
foreach (var file in files) {
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File not found for this path: {0}", file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting... and how can i print all the files?(not just [1], i have about 100 files in that list(without foreach if possible)). Also, how can i print the exact file missing? Ex: Console.WriteLine("File not found {0}", filename) ?

Comment: Updated, code should print out every file's name, and also print out the file name upon error.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
List<string> missedFiles = new List<string>();
if (File.Exists("list.txt"))
{
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("list.txt"))
    {
         if (File.Exists(line))
         {
             Console.WriteLine(files[1]);
         }
         else
         {
             missedFiles.Add(line);
         }
    }

    if(missedFiles.Count>0)
    {
        foreach(var file in missedFiles)
           Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}

Console.ReadKey(true);
```